# Is it possible to link Owasp Zap and Browserstack,Crossbrowsertesting.com or SeleniumGrid?

Tags: security, testing, owasp, zap, security-testing

**Details:**

Currently I used Owaspzap with a connection to Postman, and via the api in the local area. But we also want to connect to Browserstack or Crossbrowsertesting.com to test our mobile pages for security issues.
Even after intensive research, I have not yet found a way to link Browserstack and Owasp Zap with each other via the proxy.
Of course, Owasp Zap can be tested on direct physical hardware (i.e. mobiles) with appropriate solutions.

But is it also possible to establish a connection to various browser solutions such as Browserstack or Crossbrowsertesting?

The Selenium Grid approach would also be very interesting in this context.

**Question:**

Is there a possibility to link Browserstack or Crossbrowsertesting.com with Selenium Grid via the Owasp Zap Api?

Comment: Can Browserstack or Crossbrowsertesting be configured to use a proxy?

Comment: I had already done intensive research and studied Simon's contributions and also ZAP documentations. Somehow, however, I found nothing on this point. Not even a blog entry where someone managed to do that. 

I find that a bit curious :)

Comment: Selenium Grid is still selenium, set it up to proxy through ZAP.